# Get ID of table when clicked on td function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the `id` of table when clicked on the `td` of the `table`. My code looks like:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_1">
  <thead>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td onclick="editUnit()">John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  function editUnit() {
    let tableId = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    alert(tableId);
  }
</script>
```

I have also tried with `$(this).parents('table').attr('id');` , however, still the same result of `undefined`.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwjsekLf/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that assigning the listener inline on the HTML, when the function is called, the `this` context is not pointing to `td`, that's why you get undefined.

So, you have at least two options here:

- *The "not so good" option:* pass this on the listener and get as parameter on the function, like this:

```js
function editUnit(td) {
  let tableId = $(td).closest('table').attr('id');
  console.log(tableId);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_1">
  <thead>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td onclick="editUnit(this)">John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- *The "better" option:* assign an `id` (or even a class) to the `<td>` and bind the listener on the script part, not HTML, this way `this` context will be correct, like this:

```js
document.getElementById("clickableTd").onclick = editUnit;

function editUnit() {
  let tableId = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
  console.log(tableId);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_1">
  <thead>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="clickableTd">John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the code as below

```
<td onclick="editUnit(this)">John</td>

    function editUnit(event){

  let tableId = $(event).closest('table').attr('id');
  alert(tableId);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this with total jQuery.

```
$("td").click(function(event) {
  let tableId = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
  alert(tableId);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with your code :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <table id="table_1">
      <thead>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td onclick="editUnit(this)">John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jane</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        function editUnit(event){

      let tableId = $(event).closest('table').attr('id');
      alert(tableId);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery's `.parent()` method ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/parent/))

```
function editUnit(){
  const tableId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
  alert(tableId);
}
```